# Cheap AVB (audio) setup

Tags: networking, audio, raspberry-pi, nuc

I am looking for some relatively cheap AVB talkers (approx 50-200 EUR; if that's not possible what is my cheapest option?). Most importantly talkers should have digital input(s) like S/PDIF or TOSLINK.

A plus would be additional analoge inputs.

Alternative: are there possibly *easy* self-made solutions?